# Java(kareltherobot) Issues

Tags: java, karel

I'm currently in a AP Computer Science class in high school. We are coding in Java using the "kareltherobot" packages. Here are the instructions: 
For this lab, our robot will act like a roomba. It will pick up all the piles of beepers in a room. It willkeep track of information as it does its task. It must clean up every location in the room. User must be prompted for the room to clean (world file to be read in) as well as location and direction of the robot's initial state.

Information to be reported back to user:

• Area of room

• Number of piles

• Total number of beepers

• Largest pile of beepers

• Location (relative) of the largest pile

• average pile size

• percent dirty (piles/area)

I have provided a template and a world to test. Because we are at the initial stages of learning to program and test, I am providing the test world. It is a good idea to consider the test cases that may break your code, and try to test these cases during development.

Here is my current code. My issue is that I am in-able to make the robot go to the south east corner. I was attempting to have it go there and then have it move over and use the method clean row. In this way it would clean each row one by one. Can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import kareltherobot.*;


public class Driver implements Directions{
    public static int locationx2;
    public static int locationy2;
    public static String direction;
    Direction direction2;
    int beeperspicked;

    Robot r ;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // LEAVE THIS ALONE!!!!!!
        Driver d = new Driver();
        d.getInfo();
        d.cleanRoom();
        //d.printResults();
    }

    private void printResults() {
        // A bunch of System.out.prints go here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of piles was" + );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Area of room was" + );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of beepers was" + beeperspicked );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Largest pile of beepers was" + );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Location of the largest pile was" + );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Average pile size was" + );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The percent dirty was" + );
    }

    private void cleanRoom() {
        // all the code that cleans and counts goes here
        // obviously, lots more here
        r= new Robot(locationy2,locationx2,direction2,0);
        beeperspicked= 0;
        int loop= 2;
        while (r.frontIsClear()){
            while (!r.facingEast()){
                r.turnLeft(); }
            while (r.facingEast()){
                r.move(); }
        }
        while (!r.frontIsClear()){
            r.turnLeft();
        }

















        while (loop==0){
            cleanRow();
        }

    }   




    private void cleanRow() {
        while (r.nextToABeeper()== true) {
               r.pickBeeper();
               beeperspicked++;}
        while (r.frontIsClear()== true)  {
                r.move(); }
        while (!r.frontIsClear()){
            r.turnLeft();
            r.turnLeft();
        }
        }

    private void getInfo() {
        // this method acquires the starting street, avenue and direction
        // of the robot from the user.  Also it inputs the name of the world
        // file.  It then opens the world file and creates the robot
        String worldname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("World Name?");
        String locationx = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X Coordinate?");
        locationx2 = Integer.parseInt(locationx);
        String locationy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Y Coordinate?");
        locationy2 = Integer.parseInt(locationy);
        String direction = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Direction to face?");
        if (direction.equals("North")) {
            direction2= North;
        }
        if (direction.equals("East")) {
            direction2= East;
        }
        if (direction.equals("West")) {
            direction2= West;
        }
        if (direction.equals("South")) {
            direction2= South;
        }
        else
        {
            direction2= North;
        }

        String wrldName = worldname + ".wld";



        World.readWorld(wrldName);
        //set world size?
        World.setVisible(true);
        World.setDelay(20);
    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? i.e. what kind of error are you getting?